# Use of locale option in localeCompare() method

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand the use of locale parameter in String.prototype.localeCompare() method.
The output for below two examples is the same for Spanish characters:

Without locale parameter:
Code:

```
['único','árbol', 'cosas', 'fútbol'].sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.localeCompare(b);
});
```

output:

```
["árbol", "cosas", "fútbol", "único"]
```

With locale parameter:
Code:

```
['único','árbol', 'cosas', 'fútbol'].sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.localeCompare(b, 'es');
});
```

output:

```
["árbol", "cosas", "fútbol", "único"]
```

From [MDN localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare):

> Optional. A string with a BCP 47 language tag, or an array of such
> strings. For the general form and interpretation of the locales
> argument, see the Intl page.

It seems that the locale parameter does not seem to have effect on the final output of localeCompare().

Please let me know of examples where using locale paramter produces a different result.

Comment: `console.log('ä'.localeCompare('z', 'de')) //-1` while `console.log('ä'.localeCompare('z', 'sv')) //1`  from [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#Using_locales)

Comment: Yes, I think I missed this one. I'm wondering why the below two are same:
`console.log('ä'.localeCompare('z')) // -1
console.log('ä'.localeCompare('z', 'de')) //-1`

Comment: Because `ä` comes before `z` in your current locale. And the same is true for the German locale. If your locale was Swedish, then you would be getting `1`.